# Multiply a base number and increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I have a small problem, and I need some help.

What I want to do is the following.

I want the base price multiplied each time the counter is greater than 3.

An example:

if the base is 10 and the counter is 3 = 10

if the base is 10 and the counter is 4 = 20 (if it greater of 3, multiply by 2 the price base)

if the base is 10 and the counter is 6 = 30
etc...

Basically it is multiplying the base by 3 in 3.

```js
var base = 10,
    contador = 3;

var total = base + contador;
$('.result').text(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

**please if the title of the question is not correct, help me correct it**

Comment: if the counter is 6, the total 30?

Comment: what about `counter = 5`?

Comment: and when counter is 2, should the result just be 0 ?

Comment: @NinaScholz if 5, same like this if the base is 10 and the counter is 5 = 10..
if the base is 10 and the counter is 4 = 10...
if the base is 10 and the counter is 7 = 20 (if it greater of 5, multiply by 2 the price base)

Comment: @JuanDavid, please add the use cases to the question. why is 4 ten or twenty, as in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im basing the logic here:

> if 5, same like this
>
> - if the base is 10 and the counter is 5 = 10..
> - if the base is 10 and the counter is 4 = 10...
> - if the base is 10 and the counter is 7 = 20 (if it greater of 5, multiply by 2 the price base)

You can divide the `contador` by `5` and use `Math.ceil`.

```js
var getTotal = function(base, contador) {
  return base * Math.ceil(contador / 5);
}

console.log(getTotal(10, 5));
console.log(getTotal(10, 4));
console.log(getTotal(10, 7));
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: if you can help me to improve the question and the title, it would be very good, so that other people can see this question if, they come to need it :), only if you can..